# Formulário Complexo Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou criando um formulário de cadastro de cliente. Estou usando o framework Bootstrap v:3.3.7
meu fomulário de cadastro de cliente, vai abrir em um novo pop-up: width=1300, height=630.
Quando meu formulário está nesse tamanho, ele fica tudo no lugar, como na imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O problema é quando eu reduzo um pouco ele. ele acaba se destorcendo de tal maneira que fica muito estranho:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Alguém saberia me informar como eu poderia trabalhar com as propriedades bootstrap, para que eu não perdesse as proporções dessa maneira??

```html
@model Smc.Dominio.Model.EntidadeJuridicas.ClienteEmpresa
@{
    <link href="~/Template/SmcLayout/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Template/Css/smc_ligth.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        .form-control-label {
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: 300;
        }

        .form-control-sm {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            font-size: 14px;
            height: 20px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .container-fluid {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .custom {
            margin-top: 4px;
        }

        .custom-two {
            margin-top: -14px;
        }
    </style>
}

<div class="col-lg-12">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li><a href="#consulta" data-toggle="tab">Consulta</a></li>
        <li class="active "><a href="#cadastrar" data-toggle="tab">Cadastrar</a></li>

    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        @*Tab Suporte Técnico*@
        <div class="tab-pane " id="consulta">2</div>
        @*Tab Principal*@
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="cadastrar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <!--Dados Clientes-->
                    <div class="col-lg-6" style="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-control-label">Código</label>
                                    <input class="form-control-sm" type="text" style="padding:0; border-radius:1px; width:52px" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3" style="margin-left:-37px">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-control-label">Status Cliente</label>
                                    <select class="form-control-sm" style="padding:0; width:134px">
                                        <option>Pré-Cadastro</option>
                                        <option>Ativo</option>
                                        <option>Bloqueado</option>
                                        <option>Cancelado</option>
                                        <option>Inativo</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-7" style="margin-left:-49px;">
                                <div class="col-lg-3" style="margin-left:19px">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="form-control-label">Cadastro</label>
                                        <input class="form-control-sm" type="text" style="padding:0; width:78px;" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4" style="margin-left:9px;margin-right: -116px;">
                                    <label class="form-control-label">usuário</label>
                                    <input class="form-control-sm" type="text" style="padding:0;width:139px" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4" style="margin-left: -85px;margin-right: -85px;margin-top: 7px;margin-bottom: -13px;">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control-label" />&nbsp;Produtor Rural <br />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control-label" />&nbsp;Consumidor Final
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <fieldset style="border:1px solid #ddd">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group custom" style="width:100%;">
                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label">Razão Social | Nome:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-80px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100%" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group custom-two" style="width:100%;">
                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label" style="padding-left:44px;">Nome Fantasia:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-80px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100%" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group custom-two" style="width:100%;">
                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label" style="padding-left:61px;">CNPJ | CPF:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-80px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100px" />
                                            </div>

                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label text-center" style="padding-left:44px;">Insc. Estadual | RG:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-33px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100px" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group custom-two" style="width:100%;">
                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label" style="padding-left:79px;">Suframa:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-80px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100px" />
                                            </div>

                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label text-center" style="padding-left:49px;">Incrição Municipal:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-33px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100px" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group custom-two" style="width:100%;">
                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label" style="padding-left:62px;">Sub. Trib IE:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-80px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100px" />
                                            </div>

                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label text-center" style="padding-left:109px;">Cane:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-33px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100px" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group custom-two" style="width:100%;">
                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label" style="padding-left:19px;">Ramo De Atividade:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-80px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100px" />
                                            </div>

                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label text-center" style="padding-left:88px;">Vendedor:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-33px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100px" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group custom-two" style="width:100%;">
                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label" style="padding-left:52px;">Tabela Preço:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-80px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100px" />
                                            </div>


                                            @*<label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label text-center" style="padding-left:88px;">Complemento P.Física:</label>*@
                                            <div class="col-lg-4" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:126px;">
                                                <button style="width:212px; height:24px; padding-top:2px" class="btn btn-info"><i style="margin-right:9px" class="fa fa-edit"></i>Complemento P.Física</button>
                                                @*<input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100px" />*@
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group custom-two" style="width:100%;">
                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label" style="padding-left:21px;">Situação Financeira:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-80px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100px" />
                                            </div>


                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label text-center" style="padding-left:41px;margin-right:-160px">Limite De Créditos:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:126px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100px" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <fieldset style="border:1px solid #ddd">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group custom" style="width:100%;">
                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label" style="padding-left:54px">Rua | Avenida:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-80px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100%" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        @*<div class="form-group custom-two" style="width:100%;">
                <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label" style="padding-left:44px;">Nome Fantasia:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-9" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-80px;">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100%" />
                </div>
            </div>*@
                                        <div class="form-group custom-two" style="width:100%;">
                                            <label class="col-lg-3 form-control-label" style="padding-left:83px;">Número:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-1" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-26px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="width:53px" />
                                            </div>

                                            <label class="col-lg-1 form-control-label text-center" style="padding-right:44px;margin-left:22px">Bairro:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-7" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:0;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100%" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group custom-two" style="width:100%;">
                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label" style="padding-left:48px">Complemento:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-80px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="min-width:100%" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group custom-two" style="width:100%;">
                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label" style="padding-left:84px;">Região:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-80px;">
                                                <select class="form-control-sm" style="height: 20px;padding: 0;width: 156px">
                                                    <option>01</option>
                                                    <option>02</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>

                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label text-center" style="padding-left:122px;">Zona:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-33px;">
                                                <select class="form-control-sm" style="height: 20px;padding: 0;width: 156px">
                                                    <option>01</option>
                                                    <option>02</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group custom-two" style="width:100%;">
                                            <label class="col-lg-4 form-control-label" style="padding-left:71px;">Município:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-80px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="width:218px" />
                                            </div>

                                            <label class="col-lg-1 form-control-label text-center" style="margin-left:67px;">Cód:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-1" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-10px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="width:79px" />
                                            </div>

                                            <label class="col-lg-1 form-control-label text-center" style="margin-left:63px;">UF:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-1" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-10px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="width:36px" />
                                            </div>

                                            <label class="col-lg-1 form-control-label text-center" style="margin-left:21px;">Cód:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-1" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-10px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="width:36px" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group custom-two" style="width:100%;">
                                            <label class="col-lg-1 form-control-label" style="padding-left:74px; margin-left:24px">CEP:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:20px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="width:86px" />
                                            </div>

                                            <label class="col-lg-1 form-control-label text-center" style="margin-left:67px;">País:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-1" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:83px; margin-left:-10px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="width:185px" />
                                            </div>

                                            <label class="col-lg-2 form-control-label text-center" style="margin-left:63px;">Cód Pais:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-1" style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-right:-69px; margin-left:-10px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" style="width: 46px;margin-left: -10px;" />
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--Contatos-->
                    <div class="col-lg-5" style="background-color:#808080">
                        <h3>Mundo</h3>
                    </div>

                    <!--Botões-->
                    <div class="col-lg-1" style="background-color:#00ff21;">
                        <h4>Bot</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/Template/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Você tá setando muitos atributos de forma "errada" por exemplo, você tá dando margens fixadas para os inputs e alguns labels acabam ficando por cima de algum outro componente, porque você colocar as margens e alguns outros atributos que ficam bons apenas no tamanho da Tela X que eu presumo ser a sua. Então você pode melhorar isso lendo [aqui](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/).
Também te recomendo [isso aqui](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/3.3/css/) e [aqui](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/components/forms/). Creio que será muito útil não apenas agora, mas em trabalhos

Comment: Não se ofenda, mas o seu form é um dos piores que já vi! Vc destruiu o Bootstrap colocando esse monte de style="" nas tags. O seu principal ponto de início é apagar todos os styles, só isso já vai melhorar 90% o seu código.

Comment: Sem problemas, justamente por eu saber que está ruim, foi que eu vim pedir ajuda. pesquisei bastante antes de vir aqui, porém não consigo compreender algumas coisas, por exemplo, quando se trabalha com a classe `.col-md-` ou `col-lg`, ou qualquer uma dessa, fica complicado, pq ou da um tamanho maior que eu preciso, ou meno, nunca consigo fazer com que se alinhe. ou fique do tamanho que eu preciso

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa apenas formatar melhor seu código. Vamos lá, eu percebi que você tem um formulário bastante extenso, nesse caso, você pode utilizar diferentes estilos de acordo com os inputs.

Vou tentar exemplificar e explicar o comportamento das tags.

> Primeiramente o **col**

Utilizando o **col-sm-*** ele vai escalar a partir da tela de dispositivos pequenos, posicionando os itens um embaixo do outro até dispositivos maiores onde ele se ajustará ao tamanho da página.

Se vc quiser migrar para o Bootstrap 4 tem um novo recurso que seria apenas o **col**. Ele vai criar colunas iguais em todos os tamanhos de tela e adaptar automaticamente pra você.

Exemplo:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">.col</div>
  <div class="col">.col</div>
  <div class="col">.col</div>
</div>
```

Eu também notei que você criou um grid utilizando as tags **row** e **col** em quase todo o formulário, o que não é necessário, na primeira linha por exemplo, para mostrar os itens um ao lado do outro bastava utilizar o **form-inline**.

Veja o exemplo:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Esse link tem alguns tutoriais de passo a passo que podem te ajudar a entender melhor o Bootstrap https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

Comment: A classe `col` não exite no Bootstrap 3. E a forma como esta o form a responsividade vai fazer isso com ele http://prntscr.com/o3m7s2

Comment: @Geremias sim, eu sei. Na minha resposta deixo uma dica para o usuário usar o Bootstrap 4, que já existe essa tag. O form-inline é perfeito para o que ele precisa. Pois deixará os itens alinhados por padrão e ajustará automaticamente nas telas menores, como ele destaca que seu formulário fica estranho ao reduzir a tela, esse seria o objetivo. O código não está errado, apenas mal formatado. Só estudar um pouquinho a formatação do Bootstrap que encontra o caminho.